# using Jackson for parsing retrofit response is a better option than parsing it in a custom way?

Tags: json, string, gson, retrofit

i am using retrofit api for fetching response but i have removed use of JACKSON api , from parsing section, for parsing i am using basic json parsing method, using own parsing class ( by using string convertor in Retrofit code )

So i have added Convertor like

```
    RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(API_URL)
            .setConverter(new StringConverter())
            .build();
```

I have removed JACKSON Api use like

```
    @Override
    public void success(String arg0, Response arg1) {

        printMsg (arg1.getUrl()) ;

        Dictionary<String, Dictionary<String, String>> receivedData = new StoreClass_parse(arg0.toString()).parseJsonData() ;

        for ( int i = 0 ; i < receivedData.size() ; i++ )
        {
            printMsg ( receivedData.get(Integer.toString(i)).get("id")) ;
        }
```